# Pointer inside a square bracket?

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    char *p="A for Apple";
    char q[15]="B for Ball";
    printf("x=%c y=%c\n",*(p+10)-2,*(&q[4]-2)); 
    printf("u=%c v=%c w=%d\n",p[8],*q+8,8[p]-q[8]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x=c y=f  
u=p v=J
w=4
```

Problem, I am having here is determining how `w=4` was evaluated.

What does `8[p]` means?

Comment: It means the same as `p[8]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[x]` is shorthand for `*(a + x)`. Consequently, `a[x]` is equivalent to the expression `x[a]`. (same holds for `8[p]` and `p[8]` of course ;))